# Display 2 random entries from a channel in a random order

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I have been using the following channel entries tag, thinking it was randomly selecting 2 entries from the channel on each page load, but it appears to be just selecting the first two and just ordering them randomly.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="testimonials" dynamic="no" limit="2" orderby="random"}
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to grab a random 2 entries from a channel on each page load?

Comment: Are you caching the template that your testimonials display in?

Comment: Hi. No I'm not.